# Tensor Product of Spaces has Basis of Tensor Products

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I am given the following definition of the Tensor Product of spaces

Given two vector spaces $V,W$ a vector space S is a tensor product of $V,W$ if there exists a map $M$

$$ M: V \times W \rightarrow S$$

Such that $M(x_1,x_2)$ is linear in $x_1$ and $x_2$ if $(e_1)$ is a basis of $V$ and $(e_2)$ a basis of $W$ then $M(e_1,e_2)$ is a basis of S.

Then we say that $M = V \otimes W$

So now this is certainly a definition I understand and can work with but I want to build a picture in my head about what is going on.

I know of the traditional tensor product that is given two matrices

$$A \otimes B= \begin{bmatrix} a_{00}B \ \ a_{01}B \ \ ... \ \ a_{0m}B \\  a_{10}B \ \ a_{11}B \ \ ... \ \ a_{1m}B \\ \vdots \ \ \vdots  \ \ \ddots  \ \ \vdots \\ a_{n0}B \ \ a_{n1}B \ \ ... \ \ a_{nm}B \end{bmatrix} $$

So is it safe to say that given a basis $(e_1)$ of $V$ and and $(e_2)$ of W that all the possible tensor products $uv, u \in (e_1), v \in (e_2)$ is the basis of S?

Looking at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_vector_spaces

didn't yield too much insight, as they seemed to be covering a much more general and abstract formulation that (might answer my question but) felt like overkill for my needs.

Comment: Showing that the stated basis is a spanning set for $V\otimes W$ should be a snap.  The linear independence will depend on the linearity of $M(x_{1},x_{2})$ in $x_{1},x_{2}$.

Comment: Yea the first is trivial since we are spanning all the possible basis combinations, so for linear independence its not clear how to exploit linearity for the proof

Answer (score 1):

Note that usually we'll write $x_1 \otimes x_2$ instead of $M(x_1,x_2)$. (Your $M$ is the canonical map $M:V \times W \to V \otimes W$ that sends a pair to the underlying tensor.)

Matrices correspond to linear maps, and the tensor product of matrices corresponds to the tensor product of linear maps. Given two linear maps $f_i:V_i \to W_i$, their tensor product $f_1 \otimes f_2:V_1 \otimes V_2 \to W_1 \otimes W_2$ is defined by $(f_1\otimes f_2)(v_1,v_2) := f_1(v_1) \otimes f_2(v_2).$ Then what holds is that the matrix corresponding to $f_1 \otimes f_2$ (with respect to the tensor product of the chosen bases) is precisely the tensor product of the matrices corresponding to $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Example: let $f_1:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $f(a) = (a,0)$ and let $f_2:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f_2(a,b) = a$. Choose the standard bases for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$. The matrix of $f_1$ is $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$ and the matrix of $f_2$ is $B = \begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \end{pmatrix}$. We have $f_1 \otimes f_2:\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \mathbb{R}$ defined by $(f_1 \otimes f_2)(a \otimes (b,c)) = f_1(a) \otimes f_2(b,c) = (a,0) \otimes b$. Thus in the bases $(1 \otimes (1,0), 1 \otimes (0,1))$ for $\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{R}^2$ and $((1,0) \otimes 1, (0,1)\otimes 1)$ for $\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \mathbb{R}$, we see that the matrix of $f_1 \otimes f_2$ really is $A \otimes B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.