# Uniqueness of the basis for a tensor product of vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Having in mind the following answered question:

[Tensor Product of Spaces has Basis of Tensor Products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648761/tensor-product-of-spaces-has-basis-of-tensor-products?rq=1)

about bases for a tensor product of vector spaces I wonder if that is the only way to get a basis for that tensor other than the obvious. That is, the basis ${(e_1)}\otimes{(e_2)}$ for ${V_1}\otimes{V_2}$ where $(e_1)$ is a basis for $V_1$ and $(e_2)$ for $V_2$.

In case it was not unique, would that mean a different tensor product between the corresponding matrices than the usual Kronecker product between matrices?

Comment: Bases are never unique.

Answer (score 0):

That is certainly not unique.

To begin with, there are many basis for both $V_1$ and $V_2$ so there are several choices of basis on the form $(e_1) \otimes (e_2)$ where $(e_1)$ is a basis for $V_1$ and $(e_2)$ for $V_2.$

Then, one can have "cross-bases". For example, assume that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are both 2-dimensional with bases $\{ e_1^{(1)}, e_1^{(2)} \}$ and $\{ e_2^{(1)}, e_2^{(2)} \}$ respectively. Then as a basis for $V_1 \otimes V_2$ you can take
$$\{ 
e_1^{(1)} \otimes e_2^{(1)} + e_1^{(1)} \otimes e_2^{(1)},  
e_1^{(1)} \otimes e_2^{(2)} + e_1^{(1)} \otimes e_2^{(2)},  \\
e_1^{(2)} \otimes e_2^{(1)} + e_1^{(2)} \otimes e_2^{(1)},  
e_1^{(2)} \otimes e_2^{(2)} + e_1^{(2)} \otimes e_2^{(2)}  
\}$$
It isn't certain that you can rewrite any of these basis vectors as a simple tensor product.

Maybe you have heard of [quantum entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement). The mathematical description of these consists of this kind of sums of simple tensor products. See for example [these states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement#Entangled_states).